# How can i configure team city to execute the intern's test runner with phantom js as the configured browser

Tags: unit-testing, phantomjs, teamcity, intern

I'm trying to add a team city build step for my intern unit tests that execute against a web browser, but I'm uncertain how to configure and run phantom js. I have installed this plugin in teamcity which gives me a phantom js build runner:

https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node

Currently I have two build steps in team city for this.  The first step is using the npm build runner with install and update commands.

The second step is using the command line task runner to execute 'intern-runner config=tests/intern'.

Those two steps seem correct to me, but I believe this is going to fail because phantomjs is not yet running.

Would phantomjs be started using a build step?  Or do I need to configure the build agent to be running phantomjs already (and if so how would i go about that)?